# What could be the cause of faint, periodically repeating, lines on the edge of my screen?

Tags: display, external-display, lcd

I'm seeing a pattern of 5 or 6 faint dark lines repeating on the edge of my screen, and want to know,
a) If it can be fixed (easily)? How?
b) What could be the probable cause for the issue?

I've attached a couple of images of the lines **and a GIF (from a video) which captures the repeating pattern of the lines.**

I recently moved my monitor around, and maybe nudged it a little causing some kind of hardware issue. I'm not really sure, but the problem I'm seeing started only after I moved the display around a bit. I also tested the monitor by connecting to a different laptop (and different operating system) to rule out any software/graphics issue, and the lines persisted.

**Attachments**
*Note: Due to size restrictions, the resolution of the uploads isn't great, but I've also uploaded higher resolution copies to imgur. **Due to file type restrictions, the GIF is only on imgur** [Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7c1Ta.jpg)*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also tested the monitor by connecting to a different laptop (and
> different operating system) to rule out any software/graphics issue,
> and the lines persisted.

It certainly appears to be a hardware fault in the monitor and typically, the only practical repair is to replace it.

Comment: Thinking it was a hardware fault was my first instinct as well. The reason that I still asked this question is that these lines do not show up when the monitor boots and they also do not show up immediately after connecting the display to my laptop. After a bit of usage, the lines start showing up and then they remain. (I've tested for about 8 hours of continuous usage, and the lines remained throughout). Why would this be the case?

Comment: A device like a monitor will warm up gradually inside above room temperature. So given your update, and the fact that you eliminated other causes, it still looks like a hardware issue.

Comment: That makes sense. And also fits in with my second observation, where I turned the display off for over 24 hours, and then after I turned it back on, I didn't see the lines for some time again. But this time, they showed up after a longer session of being in use than previously.

Comment: Yes.  Thanks for the update.